# Script to download music and transfer to Ipod?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ipod

I need help making a script that would do this

This is what I would do manually in terminal (I will be using the .getmusic script from 360 percents to download myspace music):

```
cd /home/eric/Music
```

to make sure music gets downloaded to `/home/eric/Music`:

```
/home/eric/getmusic.sh http://www.myspace.com/ARTIST
```

I would like to be able to enter the clipboard text automatically (I don't know how to) in place of "Artist"

music is downloaded to `/home/eric/Music` in .mp3 format

```
scp -r /home/eric/Music/* root@192.168.0.183:/var/mobile/Media/Music
```

copies music to Ipod via SSH

Comment: It's not really efficient to `scp` all files in `~/Music`, especially if the folder gets big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `mus.sh` and make it executable (`chmod +x mus.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/eric/Music
/home/eric/getmusic.sh "http://www.myspace.com/$*"
scp -r /home/eric/Music/* root@192.168.0.183:/var/mobile/Media/Music
```

Usage:

```
./mus.sh ARTIST
```